# Is this a valid counterexample for this inequality concerning the growth functions of set families?

Tags: statistics, extremal-combinatorics

Here is what I am trying to prove:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two set families, then $G(A \bigcup B,m)\le G(A,m)G(B,m)$ where $G$ is the [growth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_function#Definitions).

I think the above result holds iff both $G(A,m)$ and $G(B,m)$ are greater than or equal to $2$.

Counterexample:

Let $A$ and $B$ contain single sets which are disjoint. Then $G(A \bigcup B,1)=2$, while $G(A,1)=G(B,1)=1$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your counterexample is correct.  I think you've mistaken this inequality with another. What is true, and straightforward, is that $G(A\cup B,m)\leq G(A,m)+G(B,m)$. If you want multiplication on the RHS, then we certainly have $G(A\wedge B,m)\leq G(A,m)G(B,m)$ where $A\wedge B=\{a\cap b:a\in A,b\in B\}$.

However, your thought is correct. Notice that for integers $a$ and $b$, we have  $a+b\leq ab$ iff $a,b\geq 2$.